# What is the impact of energy control in an AC in terms of cooling and power consumption?

Tags: thermodynamics, applied-mechanics, energy-efficiency, hvac, cooling

Nowadays many inverter ACs come with energy saver modes claiming to run at 80% 60% etc…

In this case wouldnt the cooling capacity also decrease? For eg if the AC is running at 60%, the AC compressor would have to run for a longer time to maintain the desired temperature right? Which means it might forever run at that 60% to maintain that temperature?

At normal mode, my understanding is that inverter compressors would slow down (at desired temperature) and thereby power consumption would be less automatically.
Wouldnt it then range between 100% and whatever is the lowest value.So wouldnt that be more efficient than the user setting the value on their own?

To sum up my question is when is it ideal to use the power save options of an AC? and are there scenarios where this can be counterproductive?

Answer (score 2):

Inverter ACs are more efficient because a compressor running all the time at 50% is more efficient than a compressor that runs at 100% half the time.  This is because the 100% compressor has maximized losses, which increase with the cube of the flow, while cooling is proportional to flow.

So the ability of the inverter system to slow down the compressor to meet actual demand lowers our losses and results in a more efficient system.

Your example of setting a system to run at 60% or 80% would act similarly.  It is saving money at the expense of maximum cooling ability. Such a system would take longer to cool an area down but the cooling would cost less.

Comment: But if the AC were sunning at 40%/60% power ("Energy saving mode")....Wouldn't it take more time (more compressor running time) for the AC to maintain the same temperature? Thus wouldn't the overall power consumption be the same?

Comment: @VipinMenon, running at half speed for twice as long uses less energy due to losses vs cooling.